# Manipulating data from database without defined properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5

My data contains a large number of databases that contain a large (and non-constant) number of columns. Ideally, a User would select from a dropdown which database to pull data from, and then have that data read to them in the form of a chart. My problem lies in pulling data from the database.

I wish to query every column for a selected database. With the Entity Framework that I am used to using, I would have to define properties for each column to be able to gain access to that column's data. Like so:

```
public class exampleModel() {
    public int data1 { get; set; }
    public int data2 { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

However, since I don't know how many columns are in a selected database at run-time, I cannot hard-code the properties beforehand.

Additionally, because my company is using SQL Server 2000, I cannot use database-first Entity Framework, as the scaffolding system does not support SQL Server prior to 2005.

What is the correct way to handle this situation? Is there a way in which I can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to query the number of columns of a database without setting up a model class for every database? Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your table'
```

### EDIT:

So for anyone who is interested in how I ended up solving this problem, I will share my extension method. This handy little method will setup and SQL Connection and read any SQL commands that you give it, allowing you to query databases that aren't setup through the Entity Framework property system.

```
public static class ConnectionTools {
    public static DataTable GetData(this DbContext database) 
    {
        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(
                    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChartConn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                c.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
                      "SELECT * FROM Holidays", c))
                {
                    DataTable t = new DataTable();
                    a.Fill(t);
                    return t;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Note that one can easily add an extra parameter to this extension method to alter the SQL statement.

Comment: SQL Server 2000? I think I found your real issue here. I'm pretty sure it's not even supported anymore.

Comment: You can use dynamics, but there is no way to get the benefits of LINQ with respect to type-ahead if you don't have your classes defined at compile time.  The only way to do this is combine reflection and build your own models with all possible columns.  If the possible column names is fixed, then you are forced to used dynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried `SqlDataAdapter()` and DataSet -- `DataSet dsRecordSet = new DataSet();` `sqlDap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);` `sqlDap.Fill(dsRecordSet);` `return(dsRecordSet.Tables[0]);` Another method is to use the **DbDataReader**

Here is a link that should help. [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a link on [DbDataReader](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=143)

Comment: I haven't tried this, I'll experiment with it and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you have success, i have used it a few times with MVC so i didn't have to build a model for all the tables